# What does it means of Normalization term of Gibbs distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am studying about Gibbs distribution concept and I am confusing about the term" normalization ". According to the Hammersley–Clifford theorem, an random $x$ can equivalently be characterized by a Gibbs distribution
$$P(x)=Z^{-1}\exp(-U(x)) $$
where $Z$ is a normalizing constant called the partition function
$$Z=\sum_x \exp(-U(x))$$
and $U(x)$ is an energy function of the form
$$U(x)=\sum_{c \in C}V_c(x)$$
which is a sum of clique potentials $V_c(x)$ over all possible cliques $C$. A clique $c$ is defined as a subset of sites in $S$ (are neighborhood system of $x$) in which every pair of distinct sites are neighbors, except for single-site cliques

To make clearly understand, let get simple example. Assume $x$ has two values 
{0,1}. The $U(x=0)$ can be computed as

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
     \begin{matrix}
      0&8 &-8\\
      0&-8&0\\
      3&-4&5\\
    \end{matrix}
    \end{array}
\right] $$
$U(x=1)$ is 
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
     \begin{matrix}
      0&-8&8\\
      4&-5&-8\\
      7&8&-9
    \end{matrix}
    \end{array}
\right] $$

My question is that how to compute $Z$ and $P(x=0)$ as well as $P(x=1)$?

As my understand, $Z$ is normalization over all $x$. Then $Z$ is computed 
$$Z=\sum_x \exp(-U(x))=\exp(-U(x=0))+\exp(-U(x=1))$$
$$Z=10^3 \times \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      \begin{matrix}
      0.002&2.9810&2.981\\
      0.001&3.1294&2.9820\\
      0.0001&0.0546&8.1031
    \end{matrix}
    \end{array}
\right]$$

Then $P(x=0)$ and $P(x=1)$ are computed
$$P(x=0)=\frac {\exp(-U(x=0))}{Z}=\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
     \begin{matrix}
      0.5&00&1\\
      0.9820&0.9526&0.0003\\
      0.9820&1&0
      \end{matrix}
    \end{array}
\right]$$

$$P(x=1)=\frac {\exp(-U(x=1))}{Z}=\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
     \begin{matrix}
      0.5&1&0\\
      0.018&0.0474&0.9997\\
      0.0180&0&1
     \end{matrix}
    \end{array}
\right]$$

Is it correct?
Reference document in [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~acthomas/724/Geman.pdf)